# Can anyone tell me how to turn off the 'Continuous error reporting' feature in Designer

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

As I type LotusScript, Designer puts a red X in the line number gutter and underlines the text.  I find that very, very, very distracting and annoying.  I've been programming for like 40 years.  I don't need to be told before I even finish the line I'm typing that it's not complete!!  I've started writing my code in Notepad.  Anyone know how to turn that off?

thanks,
clem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two places to switch this behaviour off completely. Unfortunately it cannot be done for LotusScript only, but changes will result in disabling the check for any text- editor.

First you disable the marks in the menu:
`Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Errors`

Just play with the options or remove all check marks to disable the feature completely.

Second you could disable the messages when you try to save code with errors by changing the values for:
`Domino Designer -> LotusScript Editor -> Saving With Errors`

Comment: THANKS SOOO MUCH!  What a relief not to see that show up!  :-)